# Messenger doesn't display value after user logged out and redirect

Tags: users, 9, sessions

After my user is submitting a form, I want to logged him out, then redirect to the front page. then, display a message.

```php
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  /**
   * my logic
   **/
  if ($isDeleted) {
    $this->messenger()->addMessage('Logged out');
    user_logout();
    $home = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<front>')->setAbsolute();
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($home);
  }
}
```

This code works fine, but the message doesn't show up. I read/assumed that the messenger is linked to the current session, so by log out the user, the messenger is destroyed.

So I tried to create another messenger after the user logout, but still, the message isn't displayed.

Comment: Might seem obvious but is the "Status messages" block definitely set to show on your homepage? Do other messages display on your homepage ok?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the "user_logout()" function, the message works (so the block works)

Comment: Yes you're probably right the messages are stored via the session which is cleared on logout. Have you tried switching the position in the code of the user_logout() and the message setting? A possible alternative is you redirect to the homepage with a url parameter e.g. ?user_logged_out and then use some JS or something to create/show a message

Comment: yes, I tried to switch the code, no changes. I'd like to avoid to add parameters to the url (at the last resort, I'll probably do it)

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2009-06-15/show-you-are-now-signed-out-message#comment-12483191

Comment: There's a core issue related to this.  https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/754560